# why do i have to use Integer.parseInt?

Tags: java, parsing, types

I am new to Java so forgive me if this is a silly question.

First I did the following (this is a section from my code):

```
public static void team()
    {
        int score = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the team score...");
        calculate(score);   
    }
```

But I kept getting an error saying: "Incompatible types string cannot be converted to int".
So I thought I may need to use parsing. I did the following and it worked:

```
public static void team()
    {
        int myScore;

        String score = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the team score...");
        myScore = Integer.parseInt(score);

        calculate(myScore);

    }
```

I would like to know why there is a need for me to parse the variable "score"? In the first piece of code, I declared the variable score as an integer, so would it not store the input which I expect to be an Integer in the variable score which is then passed into the method calculate. I understand that parsing is when you convert a String into an Integer. However in this case, I do not expect the user to input a string so why is there a need for parsing?

Comment: Parsing isn't done implicitly in Java.

Comment: "Parsing is when you convert a String into an Integer" not necesarily true - Parsing means sort of "Interpreting" one type of data into another type so that they can be used for further processing e.g. `Date f = df.parse(date_string)` where df is a SimpleDateFormat object initialsed with a format specifier. This has nothing to do with String or Integers.

Comment: "I do not expect the user to input a string" - yeah, you do. You expect them to input a numeric string.

Comment: Welcome to the strongly-typed world. Type safety is either your friend and your enemy most of the time.

Comment: In this case, it's correctly informing you that you're wrong, so it's your friend. Not sure when it's your enemy.

Comment: Like I said guys, I am only a beginner :) I wonder how long it will take me to reach your level of expertise....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple reason is: because `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` [returns a String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29), regardless of what you actually want the user to input.

There's no mechanism in Java to do automatic conversion based on the type of your destination variable `myScore` (though some other languages can do this, e.g. [implicit conversions](http://java.dzone.com/articles/implicit-conversions-scala) in Scala).

You could (in principle) create a custom dialog that returns an `int` , e.g. by getting the user to choose from a pulldown list of numbers, and then no parsing would be needed. But otherwise, you have to do parsing explicitly.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you. I also like the idea of the pulldown list of numbers, might try this out!

Answer (score 1):

Because a string is stored differently than an integer. Integers are stored in binary, while as a String is a collection of characters.

Example: 
The number 14 would be stored as 1110 in Binary. However, as a String, it's stored as 00110001 00110100

Take a look at this http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/The_Characters.asp

Integer.parseInt() basically does the dirty work for you, by looking up the characters in a lookup table, and as long as they correlate with proper integer values, it coverts it over to binary form, to be stored in an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the team score...");` returns a String which you tried to store in a int. That is why you are getting the "incompatible types".
See [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more information.